# Does a Conical Intersection imply that the HOMO-LUMO gap in a molecule is very small?

Tags: biophysics, molecules, quantum-chemistry

I came across some notes in which the author swiftly made this comment, that if there's always a large gap between the HOMO and the LUMO along a chemical reaction ("large" can mean at least bigger that 1 eV), then we can rule out the possibility that a conical intersection exists in the molecule at some values of the reaction coordinates. This got me wondering. It is true that if the HOMO-LUMO gap becomes very small, it seems intuitive that there will be a conical intersection. But I don't think there's any reason for the converse to be neccesarily true. In other words (although I don't have any specific examples), i**t seems perfectly possible to me to have a large HOMO-LUMO gap and still have a conical intersection.**  Is that true, or is there any argument to argue that a CI does indeed imply the HOMO-LUMO gap is small?

Comment: If you stick to HF level of approximation for describing adiabatic electronic states then energy gap between HOMO and LUMO translates to energy gap between ground and excited electronic many body states. By definition Conical Intersection is a point in molecular geometry space where energy gap closes between two adiabatic states. So, the above statement is true in general within HF approximation (accounting for electronic correlations beyond HF can change the picture).

Comment: What do you mean by "the above statement"? which one? If what you said at the beginning was true, "energy gap between HOMO and LUMO translates to energy gap between ground and excited electronic many body states.", then my statement " to have a large HOMO-LUMO gap and still have a conical intersection"  couldn't be true!

Comment: I meant : Presence of Conical Intersection $\rightleftarrrow$ HOMO-LUMO gap $=0$ at the level of HF.